# how to implement webservice in coldfusion?

Tags: web-services, coldfusion

How to implement webservice for exporting order in coldfusion?
This means instead of exporting orders as xls it would export as a web service.
Thanks
Kishor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to do this in coldfusion is to create a CFC with the functions you want to surface to the outside world have the value of 'remote' for the 'access' attribute, this will generate a [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) webservice.

An example of how to do this (adapted from the CF docs [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec13a13-7fe2.html)):

```
<cfcomponent> 
    <cffunction name="echoString" access="remote" returnType="string" output="false"> 
        <cfargument name="input" type="string"> 
        <cfreturn arguments.input> 
    </cffunction> 
</cfcomponent>
```

More information on how to use the built-in webservice functionality can be found [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-78b7.html).